# Homeomorphic Graph Definition

Tags: graph-theory

Do you think this definition of homeomorphism in graph theory correct?

"Two graphs are homeomorphic if they become isomorphic when all vertices of degree 2 are removed."

PS: 
1) I have not seen this definition anywhere else but I can't 100% claim that somebody else did not use it.
2) I hope it's not correct, because otherwise homeomorphism is usually made out to be much harder than it actually is by other definitions!

Comment: How do you remove all vertices from a circle graph? Also, if you are interested in simple graphs, your definition has the problem that it may leave that realm

Comment: For a circle graph, of course both compared graphs would be null as a result of this process, and null graphs are isomorphic(I think).  Can you give an example to the second problem you mentioned?